# Equivalence of Hausdorff and Spherical measure on $\mathbb{S}^{n}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, polar-coordinates, submanifold

Let $\Sigma$ be a submanifolds $C^{1}$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ $k$-th dimensional and let $g : \Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{k} \longmapsto \Sigma \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ $C^{1}$ with $g$ injective and $\text{D}g(x)$ injective.

Given $A \subseteq \Omega$ Borel set or Lebesgue measurable we define $H_{k}(g(A)) := \int_{A} \sqrt{\text{det}(\text{D}g(x)^{T}\text{D}g(x))} dH_{k}$.

$H_{k}$ defines a well defined measure invariant by $C^{1}$ reparametrization.

Now, let $E \subseteq \partial B(0,1,\mathbb{R}^{n+1})$ be a Borelian set.

We set $m(E) := \frac{n+1}{r} \lambda_{n+1}([0,1]E)$, where $\lambda_{n+1}$ is the Lebesgue $n+1$ dimensional measure and $[0,1]E = \left\lbrace tx : t \in [0,1] , x \in E\right\rbrace$.

I'd like to prove that the measure defined are equivalent.

I know there is an important characterization of uniformely distributed measure by Christensen, cited [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_measure), but since I don't have the knowledge required to understand it.

I determined a parametrization of $\mathbb{S}^{n}$, with polar coordinates I tried to compute $\text{det}(\text{D}g(x)^{T}\text{D}g(x))$, without success.

The idea was to compute the determinant cited above and compare with the integral given by the defition of $m(E)$, but I was unable to do so. Was my intetion correct ?

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: I know the answer, but the space is too small

Comment: Interesting question but when we really want to understand, we meet some problems: in the line where you introduce $H_k$ you probably mean $d^k x$. Then it is not clear to me what is $\partial B(0,1,\mathbb{R}^{n+1})$. I also don't see what is $r$ in the formula you gave for $m(E)$.  To make things simpler, you should start by making clear that $m$ and $H_k$ are measures on the same $\sigma$-algebra otherwise there is no change of them being equal

Comment: Links: [case of the sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/698735/92038); [still sphere, product of measurable spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2694331/92038) and with a Lipschitz continuity hypothesis, that [the surface measure coincides with the Hausdorff one of appropriate dimension](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3973330/92038)